# Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to use `puffing-billy` gem with `poltergeist` and I have some problems with that. My `capybara_helper.rb` contains next code:

```
Billy.configure do |c|
  c.cache = true
  c.cache_request_headers = false
  c.path_blacklist = []
  c.persist_cache = true
  c.ignore_cache_port = true
  c.non_successful_cache_disabled = false
  c.non_successful_error_level = :warn
  c.non_whitelisted_requests_disabled = false
end
```

My test is:

```
scenario 'Add new address', driver: :poltergeist_billy do
  proxy.stub("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=window.initializeGmaps&key=#{MyApiKeyGoesHere}&libraries=places&language=en").
          and_return(code: 500)
  visit new_address_path

  expect(page).to have_text('Service unavailable')
end
```

And I receive an error:

```
Failure/Error: new_address_path

     Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
       Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:33173/addresses/new' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with the following resources still waiting https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=window.initializeGmaps&key=#{MyApiKeyGoesHere}-qk&libraries=places
```

If to change driver to `selenium_billy`, so error will be:

```
Failure/Error: example.run
  Net::ReadTimeout:
    Net::ReadTimeout
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The resource url it's hanging on doesn't exactly match the one you're stubbing in puffing-billy - you probably want to stub with a regex instead to ensure the all requests to maps get stubbed.

```
 proxy.stub(%r{^https://maps.googleapis.com/maps}).and_return(code: 500)
```

Comment: I tried, and received the same error, `failed to reach server..`.